# i get ClassNotFoundException when i try to read from excel file

Tags: java, excel, exception

When i try to read from excel file using apace poi i get the ClassNotFoundException followed by other errors and i have imported all the necessary jar files in the reference library

by the way i'm still new to coding

heres the code :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilterInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.*;
import org.apache.poi.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


FileInputStream F = new FileInputStream("Carbcounting.xlsx");

    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(F);

    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

    FormulaEvaluator formulaEva = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

    for(Row row : sheet){
        for(Cell cell : row){

            System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue());


            }

        }
        System.out.println();

    }

}
```

and heres all the errors i'm getting when i try to run it :

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap
    at project.Test.main(Test.java:28)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections4.ListValuedMap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: You surely imported all the classes you obviously need yourself in your class "Test". But the error message tells you, that Apache POI also needs the org.apache.commons package. Do you have this imported in your project too? I guess not. And that is the reason for your CNFE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Add commons-collections4-x.x.jar file in your build path and try it again. It should work.

Get it from here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.0

Also, just adding up:
You are getting this error(NoClassDefFoundError) majorly for two reasons:

1. Java Virtual Machine is not able to find a particular class at runtime which was available at compile time.
2. If a class was present during compile time but not available in java classpath during runtime.