# Issue With Dependencies for Apache POI in Intellij IDEA. Inconsistent errors

Tags: java, excel, maven, intellij-idea, apache-poi

**Overview**

So I have been trying to parse an Excel .xlsx file with Apache POI and then output a PDF file using Apache PDFBox. The PDFBox portion works fine in my Intellij environment but not so much the POI part...

**The Problem**

When I run the program I get either

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException`

or

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap`

at the line

`XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new File("MY_FILE.xlsx"));`

Even though ALL of the JARs are in External Libraries!

**What I've Tried**

Now while this is an obvious dependency issue I have tried almost every combination of maven dependencies as suggested by other similar SO questions as well as checked out all of the official [POI Component Information](https://poi.apache.org/overview.html) and FAQ. Although I seem to be doing everything spot on, it just seems to randomly not find one of the two above classes. Below are a few pictures of my environment that may help to debug the dependency issue!

Intellij Project External Libraries:
[image: Dependencies]

Intellij Project Structure Modules:
[image: Compile Dependencies]

Intellij Project Structure Libraries:
[image: Maven Dependency]

**Edit 1**

Unfortunately, I already tried removing the 'xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar' from the 'org.apache.poi:ooxml-schemas:1.3' maven dependency and just leaving the other jars as well as removing that dependency as a whole with no luck. Also this is not an Intellij maven project, so I have no pom.xml in my project directories. My project uses Intellij's built-in dependency management which allows me to add dependencies from maven given a resource location.

**Edit 2**

Even after downloading the binaries from [the Apache POI site](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/poi/release/bin/poi-bin-3.17-20170915.zip) and then adding all of the JARs directly into my environment (No maven at all), there is still the same issue as described above. See below...

Intellij Project External Libraries: 
[image: Mavenless]

Stack Traces:

[image: ST1]
[image: ST2]

**Edit 3**

It worked in eclipse!!! Still does not change the fact that I would like to fix this in my Intellij environment if anyone is interested in looking into a strange problem.

Comment: definitely there is a version conflict issue. try ctrl+alt+shift+U on your pom when it's selected. try to find out similar dependencies with different versions. press shift double times and search for "XmlException" or "ListValuedMap" to find out if there is multiple versions for them between your dependencies.

Comment: @epcpu Hey thanks for the comment! I have added an edit to address this.

Comment: Looks to me like you added the main Apache POI jars, but not the dependencies. If you don't want to use maven, download the Apache POI *binary* distribution and add the jars from the lib folders as well as the main jars

Comment: @Gagravarr If you look at the 'Intellij Project External Libraries' image you will see that all of the dependency jars (i.e. xmlbeans-2.6.0, commons-collections4-4.1, and others) are on the classpath. Also Intellij's management system uses maven just indirectly.

Comment: Don't forget to update PDFBox to 2.0.11 (easy). Log4j should be updated to Log4j2 (requires some work).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and managed to fix it for IntelliJ in the following way.
My situation:
Trying to read from an excel file (.xlsx) which requires the XSSFWorkbook(file)
Using IntelliJ and having a Maven project

**The fix**
Missing dependency, in my case:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
    <version>4.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Be sure to have both the poi-ooxml and the commons-collections dependencies.

Sample code:

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(excelPath)); 
// excelPath is just my projects path to the excelfile 
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
```

This resulted in the NoClassDefFoundError and the ClassNotFound exception.

Found my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42177855/15965319

Answer (score 0):

After going through a bunch of dead ends it appears that the root cause of the issue was the fact that my Java 8 JRE installation included two of the POI JARs for some odd reason. After removing the JARs and cleaning references from my JRE it is working correctly! For anyone who seems to be experiencing a similar issue go to `<JDK_HOME>/jre/lib/` or `<JDK_HOME>/jre/lib/ext` to find the appropriate POI JARs to remove and then in Intellij remove your JRE reference followed by adding it back. After doing a quick build/rebuild it should work as expected!